# Decentralized, aggregated, selectively synced storage solution

Tags: sync, nas, onedrive, cloud-storage, offline-files

Originally, I just wanted to **synchronize** some **selected files** of my 1TB OneDrive to my **Notebook SSD** and **all my files** to my **external HDD**. Cloud storage programs (dropbox, gdrive, onedrive, resilio, syncthing...) seem to dislike two sync'ed folders with the same content on the same device, so either one has to trick them with a virtual machine, or look for another solution.

---

I thought a bit more about the **ultimate storage solution** (at least for my use case) and it got a bit more complicated, but it is a rather normal setup for many people nowadays:

- notebooks with small drives
- smartphones & tablets
- external HDDs
- (NAS)
- (cloud storage)
- SD-card (e.g. from camera)

### Aggregation (virtual drive of all available data)

On each storage device, I want to have a **virtual home drive** where all my files from all devices are aggregated. The current, active documents, photos, videos are usually available synchronized on all devices for organizing, editing, deleting, etc. Old bloat, large video files, backups might only reside in one or two locations with sufficient storage space (NAS, exHDD), but are still shown in my home drive and readily available, if connection is sufficient. Such an **abstraction layer that aggregates the data from multiple locations to a single one** could be possibly realized with symbolic links (mklink), but I guess it would require quite some administration overhead.

### Synchronization (decentralized, selective)

Next, the **different data sources need to be synchronized** (file table always, files/folders selectively) as soon as two devices can communicate (SSD <-USB-> exHDD // smartphone <-WiFi-> NAS // exHDD <-USB & Internet-> cloud). I guess this could be achieved with **[syncthing](https://syncthing.net/)**, or maybe even start with **[git](https://git-scm.com/)** (for added version control). Another option would be [**nextcloud**](https://nextcloud.com) or [**seafile**](https://www.seafile.com/), but they are both centralized approaches, which I'd like to avoid. I could imagine **blockchain storage** like [**Sia**](https://sia.tech/) or [**Storj**](https://storj.io/) to be also good contenders, but would like to hear what the community has to say. **Resilio Sync** is perfect for the decentralized sync part, but since it's closed source, I think it will be hard to combine it with the aggregation part.

### TL;DR

- aggregate all available storage (SSD, exHDD, NAS, cloud, smartphone, ...) to one virtual folder (symlink, [mklink](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/))
- synchronize decentralized between locations ([syncthing](https://syncthing.net/), git)

---

- in other words, I want a network folder with Windows offline-files and slow-link capabilities, but in a decentralized network infrastructure

*What is the status quo? Have I overseen viable solutions? Am I asking for the impossible?*

Comment: I don't think there is a status quo.  I think you find and use a set or tools that work for your needs and stick with them.  I use Resilio Sync, Linux with MDADM, Samba, NFS, and folder sync and it works to provide everything you ask.  But your setup and skill set is different so the solution for you might look different.  There are lots of ways to "skin" things, you just have to find YOUR way.

Comment: @Damon thanks for your pointing me in the right direction. Do you have any tutorials or other resources that would help in getting this set up?
Do you have this process automated?
And do you have mixed folders (P:\folder1 on SSD (fastest), NAS & cloud, P:\folder2\ on NAS (fastest) & cloud, P:\folder3\ on cloud, P:\folder4\ on exHDD (fastest) and NAS)
Resilio unfortunately can't sync two locations on single device.

Comment: The only proprietary things I use are Resilio & Folder Sync, the rest is vanilla stuff.  Folder sync is scheduled and automated, Resilio just runs as a service and is always "on". I'm not sure what you mean by Resilio cant sync two locations; I have it sync all sorts of things; personal folders, app folders with custom settings, mobile folders, etc.  Admittedly I run VMs so I have technically have 2 different Resilio instances to tie into, business vs home.  I will run Resiio in a VPS soon to provide better upload capacity.  I run cheap ol RAID10 on HDD; only SSDs for OS on workstations.

Comment: I would say draw your infrastructure on paper including what services will be ran where and just fill in with apps and services as needed.  I don't have any one tutorial.  Just google each individual piece.  Every thing I use is "free" although I did pay for Resilio Sync pro and folder sync, but you do not have to.  It has taken me years to implement, but I started with a plan on paper and just updated it as I went along and learned new things.  Just start at somethin' and stick with it!

Comment: **reg. sync of 2 local folders:** Resilio, Dropbox, OneDrive etc. won't sync c:\folder1 and d:\folder1 (SSD & exHDD or NAS). I understand, their protocol is inefficient due to communication overhead for secure internet sync, and dropbox LAN sync is actually pretty fast!
But I have a very bad feeling using different tools doing pretty much the same task, esp. automated syncing, as that usually results in chaos if not done in a very precise order.
I don't see the user's systems as entities, but the user's storage devices, which need to be in (selective) sync.

Comment: I think you're right that Resilio doesn't by default have the ability to sync two local folders with each other, although you might be able to work around that.  And your right the using two separate syncing methods on the same folder can wreck havoc.   I think the picture point is there are many software options out there and it would be best for you to conceptualize a  solution via hardware,  services and/or software based on need, then implement that solution and there is no out-of-the-box solution to your unique needs.

Comment: Are my needs so unique? I strongly disagree and see this as a huge shortcoming of current solutions -- a problem that everyone is having, but nobody strongly enough cares about or knows about it being a problem or being solvable.

Best seen in how people organize photos. Some photos here, some photos there (smartphone, dropbox, onedrive, NAS, exHDD, inSSD, SD-cards), databases from picasa, iphoto, lightroom, etc pointing to various directories.

A self-organizing storage solution would be really appreciated if it could fill those gaps in an elegant way.

Comment: Welcome to the paradox of choice https://www.ted.com/talks/barry_schwartz_on_the_paradox_of_choice.  Android, windows, mac, linux, desktops, tablets, phones, number of devices, number of users, large/small data set, secure/unsecure, mobile/local access, local/cloud storage, fast/slow access, large/small files, centralized (server)/decentralized (cloud and syncing), budget allocated to needs, skill set to manage, and, and and.... The variables is what makes each use case very unique.  We do NOT store/manage photos in how you describe because of our unique set of variables.